# OS Build information from Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have 2 computers on our network that I extract operating system information from. Both are Windows 10 computers at OS Build 19044. On computer is at OS Build 19044.1526 while the other is at OS Build 19044.1566.

The field ‘OperatingSystemVersion’ will only show 19044.

Can someone please assist me in finding a way (if possible) to get the 1526, or 1566 part of the OS Build using Powershell. When I use the WINVER application I see Version 21H2 (OS Build 19044.1566).

It gives me hope that Powershell should be able to exact the data from somewhere.

Sample script below:

```
cls

Get-ADComputer -Filter 'enabled -eq "true"' ` -Properties Name,Operatingsystem,OperatingSystemVersion,IPv4Address,description,homedrive,lastbadpasswordattempt,lastlogon, lastlogon Sort-Object -Property OperatingsystemVersion |

Select-Object -Property description,Name,Operatingsystem,OperatingSystemVersion,osbuild | export-csv y:\files\All_Computer_by_OSVersion_summary.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

No, this information isn't actually stored in the directory. What you see in PowerShell is pretty much exactly what's in the corresponding AD 'Computer' object that you would see through direct LDAP access.<sup>1</sup>

If you don't have other management tools, then you will need to remotely access the computer itself, e.g. through WMI `Get-WmiObject` or WinRM `Invoke-Command` (if its firewall is configured to allow that).

---

<sup>1</sup> (For example, if you connected to AD via ADSIEdit or Apache Directory Studio.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the command locally on either PCs, run the following:

```PS
Get-ComputerInfo -Property "WindowsUBR"
```

You can run the following remotely

```PS
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "COMPUTERNAME" -ScriptBlock {  (Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" -Name "UBR").UBR }
```

Change "COMPUTERNAME" to match the PCs names.

Answer (score 0):

You can get that information by probing the computers registry. (you will need administrative permissions on the remote computers)

```
$cred = Get-Credential -Message "Please enter admin credentials"

# Get-ADComputer by default already returns these properties:
# DistinguishedName, DNSHostName, Enabled, Name, ObjectClass, ObjectGUID, SamAccountName, SID,  UserPrincipalName

# ask only for extra properties you need in the output
$propsToFetch = 'Operatingsystem', 'OperatingSystemVersion', 'Description'
Get-ADComputer -Filter 'enabled -eq "true"' -Properties $propsToFetch |
Sort-Object -Property OperatingSystemVersion |
ForEach-Object {
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $_.Name -Count 1 -Quiet) {
        # have the remote computer return a formatted string 'BuildNumber.ReleaseId'
        $osBuild = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_.Name -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {
            '{0}.{1}' -f 
            (Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" -Name CurrentBuildNumber),
            (Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" -Name UBR)
        }
    }
    else {
        $osBuild = 'Unknown; Computer is off-line'
    }
    $_ | Select-Object Description, Name, Operatingsystem, OperatingSystemVersion,
                       @{Name = 'osbuild'; Expression = {$osBuild}}
} | Export-Csv -Path 'y:\files\All_Computer_by_OSVersion_summary.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```